# Image path: Jumbotron background image doesn't show after publishing to server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the simple `HTML` code to have a `jumbotron` with a background as the following:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background: url('../../img/pills.jpg') no-repeat; background-size:cover">
```

It is working fine on localhost, but when I publish the Project files to server no images are shown.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Does it have same relative path on ther server?  ('../../img/pills.jpg') 
How about permissions? Are they set up properly for the folder? Can server access it?
What are the messages inside developer console in the browser? Are there any errors?

Comment: It may not be relevant, but there is a double-quote `"` missing near the end of your sample line of code.

Comment: If your URL is e.g. `/Home/Index`, try appending `../../img/pills.jpg` to it and see what comes back from the server: `/Home/Index/../../img/pills.jpg`

Comment: @Shoter, 1. the path is relatively the same, 2. the server has Access permissions on the folder. 3. there are no errors showing!

Comment: Try accessing the link by developer console.
Check styled element and open background in new tab.

It looks like this in chrome: http://imgur.com/a/hqf90 (need to click RMB)

By this operation we will know what kind of error you have.

Comment: @PeterB, It was a mistyping. I fixed it above.

Comment: @Shoter, I have this [link](http://imgur.com/a/EtSjP)

Comment: @PeterB I implemented your suggestion but nothing has changed.

Comment: I meant, please do it in your browser address bar. Probably gives 404, but at least then we/you are sure about that.

Comment: @PeterB, OK. I did it and I have the background shown in the browser. I didn't receive an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May want to check the path of the image file on the server and make sure background-image url is reflecting the correct path

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by providing the exact path on server `Url('/Folder2/Folder1/img/pills.jpg')` instead of

`url('../../img/pills.jpg')`.